# In-memory SQLite database shared by multiple processes

Tags: sqlite

I have a system where multiple processes successfully share a single SQLite disk based database. The size and nature of the database is such that faster access is always desirable and database is temporary anyway, so keeping it fully in memory sounds like a good idea. I know SQLite supports [in memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) but it appears as if there is no way to share an in-memory database with another process (or at least this is how I understand it). Considering SQLite seems to use [file mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I see no reason why a process-shared in-memory database could not exist (at least in theory).

I am keen to know if anybody knows a way to do this or has some other suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It is true, that SQlite does not support sharing a memory database with other processes. There is little reason to implement such a feature, because uses cases are mostly artificial. You cite performance as a use case, but you can just create a file based database on a tmpfs if you are on Linux. Otherwise you can still use a number of pragmas, such as `PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;` to speed up your database by giving up durability. Going further, you can use `PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;` to prepare commits in memory or even use `PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;` if you do not need transaction support at all.

One of the main reasons for the lack of support is the need for locking. SQlite needs some means to lock the database and currently these locking operations tied to the file operations in the SQlite VFS implementation. You might still be able to implement your own VFS module that works in memory, but you risk implementing a filesystem.